# How to parse JSON boolean value?

Tags: java, android, json, boolean

I have a JSON object

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
```

I'm able to populate the object successfully but, when I try to parse a `boolean` JSON value I get an error:

> 08-28 15:06:15.809: E/Buffer Error(31857): Error converting result
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Boolean

I do it like this:

```
boolean multipleContacts = (Boolean) jsonObject.get("MultipleContacts");
```

My JSON object graph is very simple, the boolean is stored in my database as BIT field (0 or 1)

How do I solve this ?

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "ACCOUNT_EXIST": 1,
    "MultipleContacts": 0
}
```

Comment: Those are not boolean. JSON Accepts boolean values true and false.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A boolean is not an integer; `1` and `0` are not boolean values in Java. You'll need to convert them explicitly:

```
boolean multipleContacts = (1 == jsonObject.getInt("MultipleContacts"));
```

or [serialize the ints as booleans from the start.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496412/139010)

Comment: A think it would be `0 !=`[...]. At least it is in almost all languages.

Comment: More precisely "Unlike in many C-derived languages, in Java a boolean is not an integer..."

Answer (score 54):

Try this:

```
{
    "ACCOUNT_EXIST": true,
    "MultipleContacts": false
}
```

Comment: I cant change my JSON

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{
    "ACCOUNT_EXIST": true,
    "MultipleContacts": false
}

boolean success ((Boolean) jsonObject.get("ACCOUNT_EXIST")).booleanValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast this value to a Boolean in a very simple manner: by comparing it with integer value 1, like this:

```
boolean multipleContacts = new Integer(1).equals(jsonObject.get("MultipleContacts"))
```

If it is a String, you could do this:

```
boolean multipleContacts = "1".equals(jsonObject.get("MultipleContacts"))
```

Comment: Why is either of these better than using `JSONObject#getInt()`?

Comment: It really isn't - I just gave an answer that could fit a code that wasn't even using JSON.